# How to reset your keyboard on OS X 10.10.4

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard number pad has been messed up ever since I installed OS X 10.10.4.

The numbers type as follows:

when I press "1" increase volume key goes up as well.

When I press "2" the ' key comes up as well.

"3" some wired key.

"4" ] comes up.

"5" [ comes up.

And "6" the equals sign comes up.

And vice versa for the concurrent keys. 7 and 8 as well as their shift keys work fine, 9 highlights everything in shift and goes to the beginning.

I've tried a reinstall and a separate Bluetooth apple wireless keyboard I have seems to work fine.

Please help I've scoured the Internet for answers, nothing has worked.

Comment: When a separate keyboard works fine, it often indicates that the problem keyboard has physical damage.

Comment: what is your setting for the keyboard input source ?

Comment: The Bluetooth keyboard does not have a numbers pad section.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant the number section above the letters.

Comment: The setting is US English

Answer (score -1):

You would have to open up your mac and unplug the keyboard cord power up the mac and then plug it would be a hard reset

Comment: This answer doesn't really make any sense, could you perhaps try using some punctuation in there?